# Is it possible to set a class variable using a different variable type

Tags: c#, class

is it possible to set a c# variable with a different variable type value than what the variable one is setting?

```cs
public class Test{

   public DateTime TimeSinceEpoch {
      get {return TimeSinceEpoch; }
      set{ 
         DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
         TimeSinceEpoch = Epoch.AddMilliseconds(value);}} //<-the value that's expected is a DateTime value..
}
```

> How can i write:
>   'TimeSinceEpoch = 1549090800000'
>   and use TimeSinceEpoch as a normal DateTime variable?

**Without Having tow sepperate get and set variables inside the class**

Comment: what do you want to set `TimeSinceEpoch ` ?

Comment: Note that your current code has infinite recursion.  That won't by itself prevent compiling, but there is no backing variable, just a circular reference back to the same property.

Comment: Why not make another class method called for example SetTimeSinceEpoch(long milliseconds) that does the assignment you are looking for. Don’t use = for direct assignment unless you are using the same type.

Comment: Yeah i know that the current code will not compile, my question is if it is possible to set a variable with a different variable format than the root element

Comment: @Steinar: Well you aren't actually asking about a variable, but a property.  Makes no difference.  You can set it with a different type if an implicit conversion exists.  And in C#, not otherwise.

Comment: @BenVoigt What do you mean with implicit conversion?

Comment: Implicit conversions are described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions  They can be created using `operator implicit`, but you aren't the author of `DateTime` or `long` so that approach won't work here.

Comment: Implicit conversion is a conversion for which you don't need to do an _explicit_ cast (conversion). (for example: `int a = 5; float b = a;` the integer a is implicitly convertible to a float without you needing to write `float b = (float) a;`)

Comment: If your code did work. What would you expect to happen when you put a real DateTime on the right hand side of the = sign? It wouldn’t make sense to do that anymore. Therefore your idea cannot be allowed unless the object on the right could implicitly be converted to your variable type.

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk when using the `set` you as a developer choose to set what you want to set the property equal to, one could probably fix that problem by having error handlers that checks what type of variable that is sent into the `set` function

Comment: "Is this possible" is a valid question, even if it's not (possible) so I don't agree with the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't allowed even in C++/CLI which *does* have a syntax for it:

```
public ref struct Test
{
    property System::DateTime TimeSinceEpoch
    {
        DateTime get();
        void set(DateTime);
        void set(long long);
    }
};
```

You get the following error:

> error C3902: 'set': type of last parameter must be 'System::DateTime'

Intellisense actually produces two complaints, depending on which order you write them:

> E1930:    a 'set' accessor was already declared for this property at

or

> E1942:    the last parameter of the 'set' accessor does not match the property type

The underlying problem is that a .NET property has to list a type and a maximum of one setter in the metadata (Have a look at [`PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getsetmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2) -- it returns one setter or `null`, not an array).  Even though you could easily overload the setter function itself:

```
void set_TimeSinceEpoch(DateTime)
void set_TimeSinceEpoch(long)
```

only one of these two functions could be associated to the property.

You could use a helper type to allow multiple incoming types:

```
struct SuperDateTime
{
    public DateTime Value;
    public static implicit operator SuperDateTime(DateTime d) { return new SuperDateTime { Value = d }; }
    public static implicit operator SuperDateTime(long x) { return new SuperDateTime { Value = Epoch.AddMilliseconds(x) }; }
    public static implicit operator DateTime(SuperDateTime d) { return d.Value; }
}
```

but this will break readers of the property, who now have to say `TimeSinceEpoch.Value` before using a member (if passing as an argument to another function, the implicit conversion will kick in).  To overcome that, you'd need to write a forwarding function for every single member `DateTime` has.

Answer (score 0):

You need a private variable for DateTime and a long property.  See code below :

```
    public class Test
    {

       private DateTime Epoch { get;set; }
       public long TimeSinceEpoch {
          get {return  Epoch.Ticks; }
          set{ 
             DateTime temp = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
             Epoch = temp.AddMilliseconds(value);
          } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: This fails the "and use `TimeSinceEpoch` as a normal `DateTime`" goal stated in the question.

Comment: The code is just a sample and needs some minor tweaks.  I just posted the missing private variable.  I know the code as posted isn't going to properly convert unix time to windows time.

Answer (score 0):

You may just use it the way you do and to get Milliseconds:

```
var ms = (TimeSinceEpoch - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliSeconds;
```

or maybe create an extension method for it like:

```
public static class Extensions
{
     public static long MilliSeccondsSinceEpoch(this DateTime d)
     {
         DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
         return (d - Epoch).TotalMillisecond;
     }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
TimeSinceEpoch = DateTime.Now;
var ms = TimeSinceEpoch.MilliSeccondsSinceEpoch();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as i wanted it to. Hope it helps somone else

```
public class Test{
   private DateTime Time {get;set;}
   public object TimeSinceEpoch {
      get{
         return (DateTime)Time
      }
      set{
         DateTime x = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
         Time = x.AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(value));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This fails the "and use TimeSinceEpoch as a normal DateTime" goal stated in the question, because anyone reading from the property will have to apply a cast.

Comment: Your edit did precisely nothing.

Comment: @BenVoigt : The new code uses a variable (Time) and a property (TimeSinceEpoch) while original code only had a property.

Comment: @jdweng: The essential change was to make the property type `System.Object`.  Adding the field fixed the infinite recursion but didn't address the main point of the question in any way.

Comment: Look closer at solution and original code.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using implicit casts:

```
public struct EpochBasedDateTime
{
    public EpochBasedDateTime(DateTime value) => Value = value;
    public EpochBasedDateTime(int milliseconds)
        : this(Epoch.addMilliseconds(milliseconds)
    {
    }

    public static readonly DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1);
    public DateTime Value {get;}
    public static implicit operator EpochBasedDateTime (int milliseconds)
       => new EpochBasedDateTime(milliseconds);
    public static implicit operator DateTime (EpochBasedDateTime date)
       => date.Value;
}
```

So you can

```
public class Test
{
    public EpochBasedDateTime TimeSinceEpoch {get; set;}
}

var test = new Test();
test.TimeSinceEpoch =  12345;
DateTime dt = test.TimeSinceEpoch;
```

However, you're probably better off explicitly converting your number to a date using a utility method:

```
public static class Epoch
{
    public static readonly DateTime Value {get;} = new DateTime(1970,1,1);
    public static DateTime AddMilliseconds(ms)
        => Value.AddMilliseconds(ms);            
}
```

So you can

```
DateTime foo = Epoch.AddMilliseconds(12345);
```

or

```
DateTime foo = Epoch.Value.AddMilliseconds(12345);
```