# Convert Unix Epoch Timestamp to DateTime and back

Tags: c#, datetime

I convert the date and time 19/03/2019 14:23:00 into a Unix Epoch TimeStamp and then back into a DateTime object. The conversion succeeded excepting the year, which resulted 0050 in stead of 2019. I do not know what I did wrong in the conversion process, back to DateTime. The code is the following:

```
DateTime targetDateTime = new DateTime(2019, 03, 19, 14, 23, 00, DateTimeKind.Local);
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);    
long unixDateTime = (long)(targetDateTime.ToUniversalTime() - epoch).TotalSeconds;
TimeSpan resultingTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(unixDateTime);
DateTime localDateTime = new 
DateTime(resultingTimeSpan.Ticks).ToLocalTime();
```

The localDateTime.Year resulted: 0050
Please help.

Comment: See [`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You don't use `epoch` when you convert from unix time to local time. You need to be doing something like `epoch + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(unixDateTime)`

Comment: This look very similar to yesterday posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318827/is-it-possible-to-set-a-class-variable-using-a-different-variable-type/55318888#comment97364645_55318888

Comment: @canton7 I tried: DateTime dt = epoch + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(unixDateTime); The year realy resulted 2019 but this time the resulting time is 12:23:00 and not 14:23:00 as it should be.

Comment: @user2102327 you're probably hitting differences between UTC and local time? Without seeing your exact code I can't tell, but your `dt` is probably in UTC, whereas `targetDateTime` started off in local time. When you're jumping between timezones like this, it's almost always better to use `DateTimeOffset` rather than `DateTime`.

Comment: @canton7 Thank you very much! You are absolutely right. I wrote: DateTime dt = (epoch + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(unixDateTime)).ToLocalTime(); and the result is completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to get the ticks from a datetime value and then convert it back to the original datetime value, you can use the following code

```
DateTime targetDateTime = new DateTime(2019, 03, 19, 14, 23, 00, DateTimeKind.Local);

var totalTicks = targetDateTime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks;

DateTime localDateTime = new DateTime(totalTicks, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime();
```

If you still want to get the ticks value regarding the epoch time, then this code can help

```
DateTime targetDateTime = new DateTime(2019, 03, 19, 14, 23, 00, DateTimeKind.Local);
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
long unixDateTime = (targetDateTime.ToUniversalTime() - epoch).Ticks;

 //Add the ticks back to the epoch
 var utcTime = epoch.AddTicks(unixDateTime);
 DateTime localDateTime = utcTime.ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: I suspect they probably care about converting it to a Unix Epoch TimeStamp, which is why they put "*I convert the date and time 19/03/2019 14:23:00 into a Unix Epoch TimeStamp*" at the start of their question...